# Run batch file in table trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, triggers

I need to run a batch file on one of my database tables. The best solution for me is to run it in a trigger. I'd like to know whether it's a good idea or not. And in case it isn´t what other solutions could I implement?

-I need to run it everytime there's an insert or update.

-My bat file takes 20-30 seconds to finish.

-The table has around 10 inserts a day.

Comment: "The best solution for me is to run it in a trigger" - Why?

Comment: and when and why is triggered your trigger?

Comment: @JimmyB I need to run it everytime there's an insert or update. At the moment I'm doing it manually. The table has around 10 inserts a day, I forgot to say it on the post.

Comment: *"The best solution for me is to run it in a trigger"* It really isn't, in fact, it's probably one of the worst. To run a batch file, from SQL, you would need access to `xp_cmdshell`, which means you **must** be a `sysadmin`; so anyone that isn't a `sysadmin` can't `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the table. Also, if the process fails, for whatever reason, then your `INSERT`/`UPDATE` will be rolled back. I think we need to understand what it is you're trying to really achieve here; this has the smell of an [xy question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JaimeDrq Just updated post. Why? I need to get information from the table to pass it as parameters to my batch file.

Comment: How are your updates being executed? Are they being ran manually in management studio or coming from an external program?

Comment: @BarryPiccinni From an external program. Updates and inserts.

Comment: So, you want any insert or update to this table to be delayed by 30 seconds whilst this batch file runs, and if there are any problems raised by the batch file, for the original action (insert/update) to be rolled back? Because that's what you'll get from a trigger. Perhaps instead you should be looking at some kind of *queueing* action, say Service Broker?

Comment: @Larnu I'll try a bit better. I've got a batch file which gets information from one of the tables and uses it in another program, easy script. At the moment I'm doing this manually (run the batch file every time insert/update) as I mentioned before. I want this to be an automatic process.

Comment: YOu need to update your post with **specific** details. *"uses it in another program"* doesn't give us any details. Why doesn't the "other program" just connect to SQL Server? Don't reply to my comment, update your question.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Basically what I was trying to achieve is: After an insert/update to the table, run the batch file. I will look up the queueing actions, thanks!

Comment: @Sandritto Is it possible for you to run the batch file from the program? Whilst it might seem like something SQL Server can handle, it may be more practical to have your program execute your insert/update command then run the batch file on completion?

Comment: @BarryPiccinni Actually I can. I am doing it like this at the moment. After the insert is done I manually (from inside the program) run the batch file. The problem is the batch file needs a parameter which I type by hand. This parameter is one of the fields in the table that is inserted. That's why I thought of the trigger. Don't know if I explained myself very clear...

Comment: @Sandritto When you say you are running it manually, it implies you are running your query then typing a separate command that runs the batch file. I was suggesting you have your program execute the SQL and the batch file. If it requires a parameter, I'd put your update/insert in a stored proc which returns this parameter, then your program shouldn't need your input to execute the batch file?